# Docker Compose how to change IP Port to 0

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

This is my docker containers list of ports when running:

443/tcp
0.0.0.0:59541

59541/tcp
0.0.0.0:53620

59542/tcp
0.0.0.0:53621

80/tcp
0.0.0.0:59542

Is it possible to change the ones for 59541/tcp and 59542/tcp to 0.0.0.0:0?

This is my docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  appone.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apponeapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AppONE.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - ${NETWORK}
    ports:
    - "59541:443"
    - "59542:80"

networks:
  dev-network:
      name: ${NETWORK}
```

This is the docker compose override:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  appone.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "59541"
      - "59542"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Comment: I have another container that does that though? It shows 0.0.0.0:0 against the internal port

Comment: I am currently unable to connect to my container due to this.

Comment: When you say "change to 0.0.0.0", what are you trying to change exactly?  Can you say more about the connectivity problem you're having (what URL are you trying to connect to, from where, with what error)?

Comment: (The Compose port setup looks unusual to me, and possibly you can delete the `ports:` from the override file.  The first file publishes container port 443 to host port 59541, and container port 80 to host port 59542; the second publishes _container_ ports 59541 and 59542 to arbitrary-chosen host ports, but I suspect nothing is listening on those container ports.)

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. I updated my question to specify which port I wanted to bind to 0.0.0.0:0 . Also, i followed your advice and remove ports: from the override file. As a result, 443/tcp and 80/tcp are bound to 0.0.0.0:59541 and 0.0.0.0:59542 respectively. However, I get this error when I try to access them in Postman: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/error-client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established/125031